# program to find the smallest and largest word

Tags: c, string

This is an example from K.N. King book which finds the smallest and largest word in a series of words and stops at word length of 4. But it doesn't work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 20


int main(void) {
    char smallest_word[N];
    char largest_word[N];
    char current_word[N];
    printf("Enter word: ");
    gets(current_word);
    strcpy(smallest_word, strcpy(largest_word, current_word));
    while(strlen(current_word) != 4){
        printf("Enter word: ");
        gets(current_word);
        if(strcmp(current_word, smallest_word) < 0)
            strcpy(smallest_word, current_word);
        if(strcmp(current_word, largest_word) > 0)
            strcpy(largest_word, current_word);

    } 
    printf("\nSmallest word: %s\n", smallest_word);
    printf("Largest word: %s\n", largest_word);
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose I type:

```
cat 
dog 
catfish
bear
```

gives

```
Output:
Smallest Word: bear
Largest Word: dog
```

which I think is wrong.

Comment: you think wrong, the result is right :)

Comment: but the code is awful...

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin, It might be more useful if you could highlight _why_ the code is awful :)

Comment: @AnishRam some of the highlight are: `gets`, the initial `strcpy` line, not flushed `printf`s, fixed width char arrays and no bounds checking and the always horrible coding style :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I one had a manager with a good phrase, "works as coded"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we arrange the four words in the [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), we get:

- bear
- cat
- catfish
- dog

Thus the output looks correct ("bear" is the first, and "dog" is the last).

Comment: So, it means strcmp() function work according to lexicographic order.

Comment: I thought it compares strings according to their length

Comment: @ashish2expert: Lexicographic order, not length. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/